# Cómo puedo transformar un string a Date en Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Estoy intentando convertir mi string a Date porque en mi api lo tengo como Date el formato de la fecha lo tengo en la api en ISO8601y transformé la fecha a ISO8601 mediante `.toISOString()` pero esto hace que no pueda pasarlo a la api porque como lo dije lo tengo en tipo `Date`, estoy usando moment.js para hacer esto:

```
formatDate(input: Date): string {
    return moment(input).toISOString();
}
```

tengo esa función para transformar la fecha a ISO8601 y acá quiero agregarle la `hora` que seleccione el usuario  a esa `fecha` por eso usé `.substr()` para quitarle la hora y minutos al ISO8601 pero tengo algunos problemas con esto, quisiera saber si hay alguna mejor forma de hacerlo:

```
const fechaSeleccionada = this.formatDate(this.state.date);
const Hora = this.state.hora;
const fechaHora = fechaSeleccionada.substr(0, 11) + Hora + ':00';
const fechaFormatDate = new Date(fechaHora)
```

Esto me devuelve la fecha así `2021-05-11T16:00:00.000Z` realmente no sé por qué, lo que quiero es tener la fecha pero sin el `.000Z` y que salga la zona horaria de mi zona que es `-5:00`

Answer (score 0):

No sé que tipo de backend tienes pero por si acaso no probaste pasar el string a la api? generalmente aceptan igual dependiendo de cuál es

Comment: No lo he probado, lo probaré

Comment: Php y Javascript por ejemplo son lenguajes no tipados (no se declaran los tipos de datos) por lo que si reciben una cadena o numero depende de que hagas con ese dato no importa, aunque generalmente si se recomienda a veces hacer un cast o algo para asegurarse de que sea el tipo que quieras. Saludos